# Updating graphics in JPanel when button is pressed

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

My main class extends JFrame and has a JPanel containing a graphics component, previously I had the following code:

```
    public class StartGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public StartGUI {

    graphArea = new JPanel() {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            drawNetwork(myNetwork, this, g);
                }
};

            add(graphArea);
        }
```

However now I wish to change the graphics area to display only after I press a JButton, how would I move this JPanel to update drawNetwork in the actionPerformed method?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == readButton) {
        graphArea = new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                drawNetwork(myNetwork, this, g);

            }
        };
    }
```

The above does not seem to work, how would I fix this?

Comment: Can't you just create the graphArea and make it insisible. call graphArea.setVisible(true) in the actionPerformed()

Comment: No, as this is a simplification of my code. The real button prompts a file picker which changes which graph is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fasr as I understand from your comment you need just to separate model (myNetwork) and view (the graphArea).

Create and add the graphArea but

```
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (myNetwork!=null) {
                drawNetwork(myNetwork, this, g);
            }
        }
```

Initilly the network is null (or it could be some isInitialized() check). As soon as the file is selected and the network is created just call graphArea .repaint() to reflect model changes.

Answer (score 0):

You create new graphArea JPanel, but do not add it to any container. In your old code you have a call `add(graphArea);` which is missing in the new code.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, I was really hoping to be able to simply update the paintComponent without creating a new JPanel each time

Comment: You don't have to create new panel each time. In fact, you shouldn't. Just keep the reference as a field in the class and use it in listener.